# Как реализовать многопточность интерфейса в qt

Tags: c++, qt

Задача стоит достаточно простая есть несколько элементов в форме. Есть график функций который должен обновляться в реальном времени, и есть дополнительные элементы в виде настроек программы. По отдельности все это реализовано, но не могу сделать так, что бы это работало одновременно.  Пытался сделать с помощью QThread и QtConcurrent но ничего не получилось.
Много не прошу, прошу объяснить на простом примере есть функция которая постоянно генерирует новый цвет для кнопки нужно вывести ее в независимый поток.

вот код для генерация цвета

```
ui->label->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb("+QString::number(rand()%255)+", "+QString::number(rand()%255)+", "+QString::number(rand()%255)+");");
```

Comment: а вариант "обновлять форму по событию таймера" не подходит? Судя по тексту вопроса, данные уже есть, нужно просто обновить состояние компонентов на форме. Как по мне, сигнал таймера `timeout()` как нельзя кстати подходит для этого.

Comment: данные постоянно будут приходить, а по поводу таймера не получится ли так что мне будет приходиться ждать  пока функция завершит свое выполнение прежде чем я смогу дальше работать, если получается так то не мой вариант

Comment: все спасибо заработало

Comment: работу с интерфейсом выносить в отдельный поток (почти) невозможно